# How to use a generic type parameter as type parameter for a property declared as an interface with type constraints?

Tags: c#, generics

How do I declare and use generic interfaces (see namespace Sample2) to work in the same way as with classes in namespace Sample1?

I know there is a workaround (see namespace Sample2Modified) but that is not what I'm trying to achieve.

---

### Works with classes

When using classes, this works fine:

```
namespace Sample1
{
    public class ClassContainer<T1, T2>
        where T1 : T2
    { }

    public class ClassParent
    { }

    public class ClassChild : ClassParent
    { }

    public class ClassSampleDoesWork<TItem>
        where TItem : ClassParent
    {
        ClassContainer<IEnumerable<TItem>, IEnumerable<ClassParent>> SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

### Does not work with interfaces

However, with interfaces the compiler gives this warning when declaring the property in ClassSampleDoesNotWork:

```
Error 16 The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TItem>'
cannot be used as type parameter 'T1' in the generic type or method
'Sample2.IInterfaceContainer<T1,T2>'. There is no implicit reference
conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TItem>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Sample2.IInterfaceParent>'.
```

Code:

```
namespace Sample2
{
    public interface IInterfaceContainer<T1, T2>
        where T1 : T2
    { }

    public interface IInterfaceParent
    { }

    public interface IInterfaceChild : IInterfaceParent
    { }

    public class ClassSampleDoesNotWork<TItem>
        where TItem : IInterfaceParent
    {
        IInterfaceContainer<IEnumerable<TItem>, IEnumerable<IInterfaceParent>> SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

### Modified version works, but this is not really what I want

If I modify the class to have TEnumerableOfItem instead of TItem, it works:

```
namespace Sample2Modified
{
    public interface IInterfaceContainer<T1, T2>
        where T1 : T2
    { }

    public interface IInterfaceParent
    { }

    public interface IInterfaceChild : IInterfaceParent
    { }

    public class ClassSampleModifiedDoesWork<TEnumerableOfItem>
        where TEnumerableOfItem : IEnumerable<IInterfaceParent>
    {
        IInterfaceContainer<TEnumerableOfItem, IEnumerable<IInterfaceParent>> SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The version with the classes didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add `class` constraint to the `TItem`:

```
namespace Sample2
{
    public interface IInterfaceContainer<T1, T2>            
        where T1 : T2
    { }

    public interface IInterfaceParent
    { }

    public interface IInterfaceChild : IInterfaceParent
    { }

    public class ClassSampleDoesNotWork<TItem>
        where TItem : class, IInterfaceParent
    {
        IInterfaceContainer<IEnumerable<TItem>, IEnumerable<IInterfaceParent>> SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This works because variance only works for reference-types (or there is an identity conversion). It isn't known that `TItem` is reference type, unless you add `: class`.
Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) article for more information.
Here is a sample code to demonstrate this behavior:

```
IEnumerable<Object> items = new List<int>(); // Compiler error.
```